# Как сформировать наборы символов с уникальными значениями удовлетворяющими требованиям?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть 30 символов (26 знаков латинского алфавита и цифры 1,2,3,4). Необходимо сформировать 30 наборов по 6 символов в каждом, удовлетворяющие требованиям:

1. все символы распределены произвольно
2. в одном наборе из 6 символов все символы уникальны (то есть не повторяются)
3. для каждого набора из 6 символов есть другой набор, у которого совпадает только 1 символ

Как это можно реализовать через js?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Проблема в том, что я не знаю с какой стороны подойти к этому, с чего начать и как это в принципе решается

Comment: Если это учебное задание, то лучше начать с консультации у преподавателя. В противном случае, стоит начать с основ комбинаторики.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev это не учебное задание. Это задача, которую я сам себе поставил. Так как нет представления я обратился к сообществу.

Comment: Почитайте книгу по комбинаторике, правда. Ваш вопрос не по программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

```
var symbols = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234';
var symArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    symArr.push(symbols.charAt(i));
}
symArr.sort(randSort);
var savedPos = -1;
var savedChar = '';
var prevRes = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    for (var res = '', j = 0; res.length < 6; j++) {
        if (savedPos == res.length) {
            res += savedChar;
            continue;
        }
        if (prevRes.indexOf(symArr[j]) > -1) {
            continue;
        }
        res += symArr[j];
    }
    savedPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    savedChar = res.charAt(savedPos);
    symArr.sort(randSort);
    prevRes = res;
    console.log(res);
}

function randSort() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
};
```

Comment: Нет ограничения на уникальность символов в наборе

Comment: Почему нет? Есть. Символы в одном наборе гарантированно не повторяются. :)
Тут другая проблема, не заметил сразу, что должен существовать набор, отличающийся **ровно одним** символом.

Comment: Это вам кажется, что символы не повторяются. Выполняю в консоли FF получаю, например, вот такую последовательность: `nncm4h`. Или такую `sesgk2`. Или такую `2ilcec`. и т.д.

Comment: Хм, да, понял в чем проблема. Как раз исправил код, чтобы выполнялась третье условие, теперь, как и требуется, для любого набора существует другой (а конкретно, следующий и предыдущий, в которых совпадает ровно один символ (однако при этом, в списке могут существовать и другие наборы, совпадающие большим числом символов, условие этого не запрещает). Попутно должна исправиться и проблема повторов.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо. видимо я не правильно сформулировал задачу:
я получи такие варианты при выполнении вашего кода:
`jlzxue
slngif
shbwoe
thj1iy
ucjzp2
rnmay2
sdiafe
srhywt
muvcit
jfzda1
h2zvgy
sf1hjo
emvpju
fay1jk
wdyvzb
wqflux`

Comment: @Yaant спасибо. видимо я не правильно сформулировал задачу:
должно получиться следующее:
jlzxue - jkorty (с предыдущим совпадаете только j) - kqmskl (с предыдущим совпадает только k, а с первым совпадает только l) - qweonb (с предыдущим совпадает q, с первым совпадает e, со вторым совпадает o)

Comment: Ага, то есть не должно быть комбинаций, имеющих более одного общего символа? Да, тогда это будет получается несколько другая задача. Попробую подумать завтра. :)

Comment: @Yaant появились идеи? :)

Comment: @angelzzz увы, пока совершенно не было времени.

Comment: @angelzzz Наконец нашел немного времени, и мои смутные сомнения, терзавшие меня с самого начала, подтвердились: в такой формулировке (из 30 символов получить 30 наборов по 6 символов, таких, что любые два набора имеют не больше одного общего символа), решения не имеет. 
Смотрите: 1-й набор мы можем выбрать из 30 символов. 2-й — из 25 (1 символ из 1-го набора, и 24 оставшихся). 3-й – из 20 (1 символ из 1-го, 1 из 2-го и 18 незадействованных ранее). 4-й — из 15, 5-й — из 10, а вот для 6 набора у нас остается уже только 5 возможных символов. Все. Добавить 6-й символ, не нарушая условия, нельзя.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо. я тоже до этого дошел методом ручного перебора :) правильная задача: между двумя любыми наборами может быть и должен быть только 1 общий символ :)